# handling manual user creation with get_current_user() (GAE)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, authentication

I am using GAE's Python environment and [Janrain](http://www.janrain.com/) in order to provide multiple ways to login in my service.

Based on login information I receive from Janrain, I create a `google.appengine.api.User` object and store it to the datastore.  Is there a way to handle this new object with the built-in [get_current_user()](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/users/functions.html#get_current_user)?  I need to be able to determine whether the requester is logged in or not and who the user is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot use your custom user objects with the native GAE [Users API](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/users/).

You could use a sessions library to track whether or not the request is coming from a logged in user (and who that user is).  I recommend [gae-sessions](http://github.com/dound/gae-sessions/wiki).  The source includes a [demo](http://github.com/dound/gae-sessions/tree/master//demo/) which shows how to integrate the sessions library with [Janrain/RPX](http://www.janrain.com/).

Disclaimer: I wrote gae-sessions, but for an informative comparison of it with alternatives, read [this article](http://github.com/dound/gae-sessions/wiki/comparison-with-alternative-libraries).